# Vitest mock the useLocation

Tags: reactjs, vitest

I am using Vitest for my test file.Below is a piece of code.

```
const location = useLocation();
 const state = location.state as { selectedTemplateName: string }; 
 const { selectedTemplateName } = state;
```

I need to mock the above code in my test file.

Currently when I run the test file I am getting error as below.
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'selectedTemplateName' of 'state' as it is null.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

use [spyOn](https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-spyon) and `mockReturnValue`.

```
import * as useLocationHooks from '../hooks/useLocation';

describe('Test', () => {
    const useLocationSpy = vi.spyOn(useLocationHooks, 'useLocation');
    useLocationSpy.mockReturnValue({
       state: {
          selectedTemplateName: 'Music'
       }
    });
    // So on...
});
```

Comment: Can you explain if it worked for you? i am getting issues while adding this